# I want to create this query with Eloquent model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

consider the below query as an example

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE md5( category_id) = 'c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'
```

I want to create this query with Eloquent model.

I hope this time I am pretty much clear with my question :)

Comment: `$query = Model::where('category_id', md5('c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'))->get();`

Comment: its not workin givind error md5 expect parameter 1 , 0 given

Comment: Copying old question examples is quite ridiculous.. There is more than enough info at Laravel documentation > Read it >Try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use whereRaw:

```
$values=\DB::table('table_name')->select('table_name.*')
->whereRaw(" md5( category_id) = 'c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'")
->get();
```

Comment: thank you soo much its working..

Answer (score 0):

```
Model::where('field', 'value')
```

It's an ordinary request with Eloquent.

But you can't use md5 inside this function.
For this reason use:

```
Model::whereRaw('md5( category_id) = ?', ['value'])->get()
```

You can put any raw SQL where inside

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions